# Visual studio 2017: Modify the inherited values

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, wxwidgets

I was working on a project where I needed to change the inherited values in my project properties.

[image]

Problem is I am getting compiler error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/volume.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/wxprec.h': No such file or directory 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/string.h': No such file or directory
```

I checked the CTELibraries folder and there was no such folder `wxWidgets-3.2.1`. Also I am not sure how thispath came over here. Is there any way to change it to `wxWidgets-3.0.0`

[image]

Comment: Uncheck the checkbox and add the required paths.

Comment: still does not allow me to add, the field is disabled

Comment: What field? You have a big multi-line box above in your disposal.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit Inherited values field, however the first box that you see is editable but it does not have the CTELibraries value

Comment: I don't understand. It looks like you already modified the inherited values, since none of the inherited values made it into the evaluated value. The final, evaluated values look like a copy of the project-specific overrides of the inherited values. Maybe what you need to do is *eliminate* the changes to the inherited values?

Comment: *"I checked the CTELibraries folder and there was no such folder wxWidgets-3.2.1."* -- this might be true, but your screenshot is insufficient to support this conclusion. Your screenshot shows there is no `C:\CTELibraries\Libraries\wxWidgets-3.2.1`, but the inherited properties refer to `C:\CTELibraries\Libraries\wxWidgets\wxWidgets-3.2.1`. For a more conclusive result, double-click the highlighted folder (`wxWidgets`) to see its contents.

Comment: The CTE libraries aren't public. Ask a colleague or on your Stack Overflow for Teams.